# pic32 debug char pointer declaration

Tags: pic, uart, mplab, pickit

I'm working with a PIC32MX564F128H in MPLABX 2.35 with pickit3. I'm trying to parse a message from UART. The character is received properly, but I'm stalling when I attempt to copy a character to a buffer. This is the part in my main loop:

```
                unsigned char*buffer="efg"; //dummy string
                GetDataBuffer(buffer, 3);
```

_

```
  UINT32 GetDataBuffer(unsigned char *buffer, UINT32 max_size)
    {
        UINT32 num_char;
        num_char = 0;

        while(num_char < max_size)
        {
            UINT8 character;
            while(!UARTReceivedDataIsAvailable(UART1));
            character = UARTGetDataByte(UART1);
            if(character == '\r')
                break;
            *buffer = character;  **\\PROGRAM STALLS HERE** 
            buffer++;
            num_char++;
        }
        return num_char;
    }
```

Symptoms:

In debug mode, after unsigned char pointer declaration: buffer address: 0xA0008010 Value: Invalid Address

After being passed into GetDataBuffer: buffer address: 0xA00071F8 Value: 0x9D005ED8 *buffer=0x65 ("e", at this point not written over.) Continuing, program stalls at point shown above until the debugger halts at an unknown location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are having this problem because you are attempting to modify `buffer` which you defined as pointer to char, or rather point to a string literal. You cannot modify this. You should use:

```
unsigned char buffer[]="efg";
```

instead. For more information, check out this post: [Char array vs Char Pointer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186765/char-array-vs-char-pointer-in-c)

Comment: So unsigned char*buffer="efg" is actually like a unsigned char const *const buffer="efg" where change in address pointed and value is not allowed??